# Tailwindcss animation + nextjs: Image fadeIn effect only runs first time then stops

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a smooth image transition (fade in) from one image to another, for an array of images imported directly (i.e. `import img1 from './picture-1.jpg'` etc) into my nextjs component.
The component is supposed to be a large image banner. I want it to auto-swap the images.

Snippet of what I have so far that mostly works:

```js
...
...
  useInterval(nextImage, 5000)

  const bgImage = `url(${images[index]})`

  return (
    <div
      className="animate-slowfadein w-full bg-cover bg-center h-80"
      style={{ backgroundImage: bgImage }}
    ></div>
  )
...
```

The image rotation is working, but I am noticing that the animation only works **the first time the component is mounted**. After that, it's abrupt transitions all the way. How do I get each image to **always fade in**?

Comment: try changing a key in the `div` everytime the animations runs

Comment: Clever - that actually works! I find it hard to believe there isn't a less hack-y solution (though, the requirement itself is a bit hacky). If you want to put ur suggestion as an answer, happy to accept!